# Sudden "unused argument" error

Tags: r

I have no idea why but I am quite sure the following did produce a plot a while back. Can you tell me what's wrong here?

```
library(ggplot2)
qplot(c(0, 2), stat="function", fun=exp, geom="line")
```

This returns "Error in c(0, 2) : unused argument (2)." Why?

**Edit:** This is a general problem:

```
a <- c(0, 2)
```

gives the same error. What's going on here?

Comment: works for me with ggplot2 v 0.9.3.1.  Do you have a different `exp` function defined in your workspace (`getAnywhere("exp")$where`) ?

Comment: @BenBolker, please see my edit. Any idea what could cause that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Works for me with ggplot2 v 0.9.3.1.  Based on your edit, I'm 99% sure you have a different `c()` function defined in your workspace/loaded somewhere in your search path (`getAnywhere("c")$where`), which is masking the built-in version.

To test, try starting from a clean session (with `--vanilla` if possible to skip reloading workspace/executing `.Rprofile`/etc.)

If you're lucky the problem is in your global workspace and `rm("c")` will work -- otherwise you have to track down which package is loading this booby trap ... (`find("c")` could be useful in that case ...)

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem with textnets package even though the same code worked fine several months ago.

https://github.com/cbail/textnets

In my case, turns out, Bail had changed the function names and arguments, so some of the previous arguments are no longer valid! Just check which arguments the function currently takes.