# Error: unused argument (FUN = keep)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I believe I must have overwritten a function somehow by reference to 
[Sudden "unused argument" error in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24004974/sudden-unused-argument-error-in-r)

However `ggplot` without lines is a bit of a problem as I have not been able to figure it out :)

Any help gratefully appreciated

NOTE : I do not expect this to produce an error for you unless you have screwed up like I have !

```
library(ggplot2)
data <- data.frame(x=c(1,2),y=c(1,2))

ggplot(data = data, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point()  # Works 

ggplot(data = data, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_line()  # Fails
# Error: unused argument (FUN = keep)
```

Thanks in anticipation

Comment: I sympathize, but this is rather hard/impossible to debug!  Can you start from a clean R session ???  If you absolutely need to debug this you can try `traceback()` and/or `options(error=recover)` to try to figure out where things are going wrong ...

Comment: PS results of `sessionInfo()`, `traceback()` might help ...

Comment: Congratulations.  You can (and should) write up your solution as an answer, unless it seems so peculiar/idiosyncratic as to *not* be useful to future readers, in which case you should delete the question ... it's a still a little puzzling, as I don't immediately see where `ave()` should get called downstream by these functions.

Answer (score 2):

I got to the bottom of this I had overwritten a function in my local scope I called ave() - 
this is  used in stats:: - and I had not realised

My approach was simple - start a vanilla session and plot code as above

then run source libraries one by one until it broke

then  start again  running the functions in that library one by one

(and a hint - in future I will use names that other people wont - ( obvious but d'oh !)