# Error In Random Forest In R Studio

Tags: r, rstudio

I am stuck in R specially while running the summary function using Random Forest.
Everytime I use the summary function i get the below error:

`Error in print.matrix(xx, quote = quote, ...) : 
  unused argument (quote = quote)`

[One of the SO link I tried taking help from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24004974/sudden-unused-argument-error)

However with this link also, the issue has not been resolved. I restarted my R session as advised but no respite.

Comment: It appears that the issue _was_ resolved in the link that you cited.  There is an accepted answer.   Following @BenBolker 's answer there, I would suggest that you start with `ls()`.   Have you somehow redefined the `print.matrix` function?

Comment: yes i had redefined `print.matrix`. removed it using `rm` and now it is working ok